# Get SelectedItem Value while Dropdownlist Selected Index Change Razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have one Tblproduct `class` which has `List of GetTypes()` to bind it into Dropdownlist below :

```cs
public partial class Tblproduct: AuditableEntity
{
    [DisplayName("Product Type")]
    public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }


    public static List<SelectListItem> GetTypes()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> datas = new List<SelectListItem>();
    
        datas.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value="",Text=""});
        datas.Insert(1, new SelectListItem() { Value= InventoryCatalogueID.ToString(), Text="Inventory Catalogue"});
        datas.Insert(1, new SelectListItem() { Value= ServiceCatalogueID.ToString(), Text="Service Catalogue"});
        datas.Insert(1, new SelectListItem() { Value= ServiceCatalogueID.ToString(), Text= "Sub-Assembly" });
        datas.Insert(1, new SelectListItem() { Value= ServiceCatalogueID.ToString(), Text= "Raw Material" });
        datas.Insert(1, new SelectListItem() { Value= ServiceCatalogueID.ToString(), Text= "Finish Good" });
        datas.Insert(1, new SelectListItem() { Value= ServiceCatalogueID.ToString(), Text= "Service Catalogue" });
    
        return datas;
    }
}
```

And I have one `ViewModel` :

```cs
public ProductVM(Tblproduct _model = null, bool isreadonly = false):base(_model, isreadonly,"ControllerName")
{
    types = Tblproduct.GetTypes();
}
        
public List<SelectListItem> types { get; set; }
```

And I also have succeeded to bind the list of `Tblproduct GetTypes` into a dropdown in the `View` :

```
<select2 asp-for="model.ProductTypeId" asp-items="@Model.types"/>
```

And what I am struggling now is, I need to add some input based on selected types.
Do I need to use `auto-post-back` Helper to get selected value?

But if I use `auto-post-back` the dropdown will always select the first value…

Here is my imagination:

```
@if(Model.types = 'Finish Good'){
    //do something to add new input or select
}
```

But how to get the Dropdownlist SelectedIndex or SelectedText change ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.  Are you looking to perform some condition server-side when the view is being rendered based on the current value of `Model.ProductTypeId`?  Are you looking to perform some condition server-side after a form has been posted, again based on the current value of `Model.ProductTypeId`?  Are you looking to perform some *client-side* logic when the user selects an option, without having to post the form to the server?  Something else?  I suspect you're not fully understanding the sequence of events here.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I am trying to perform some condition server-side after a form has been posted based on Selected Value of Model.types..

Comment: Then isn't the selected value in `ProductTypeId`?  That's what `asp-for="model.ProductTypeId"` does, isn't it?  What is the controller action which receives this form post?  What debugging have you done to observe what that controller action receives?

Comment: What is `auto-post-back`? This is MVC, not WebForms, right?

Comment: Dear @David, yes selected value in ProductTypeID. And I am trying to add some other input field based on selected ProductTypeID. I assume it will need pure javascript selectedIndexChange to display new input field based on the selected value ?

Comment: @tryingtocode: If you're perfoming this logic server-side then you would use C#, not JavaScript.  If the value you're looking for is in `ProductTypeID` then you would check that value, not `types`.  It's not clear what exactly you're asking or what problem you're trying to solve.  You seem confused about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello, have you tried the updated solution? Did you able to resolve the issue? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the Dropdownlist SelectedIndex or SelectedText change ?

It seems, you are trying to extract submitted dropdown value from your razor page while you change dropdown value.

It can be achievable through onchnage event both using javascript or without javascript. I am showing you with razor page because javascript one is simple so you can do it by yourself.

Let's have a look in practice how we can achieve that.

First of all, we need an onchnage event which would be executed while any dropdown change event taken place.

Further more, by that submitted value, you would filter the the list and retrieve your expected value.

Let's, have a look at the code snippet:

Razor cshtml.cs:

```
public class OnDropdownValueChangeModel : PageModel
    {
        public static List<SelectListItem> GetAll()
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "0",  Text = "Please Select Value" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Inventory Catalogue" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Service Catalogue" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Sub-Assembly" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Raw Material" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "5", Text = "Finish Good" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "6", Text = "Service Catalogue" }
            };
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        public string? ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public string? SelectedValue { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            selectListItems = GetAll();
        }
        public void OnPostMyMethod()
        {
            var dropdownChangedValue = Request.Form["ProductTypeId"].ToString();
            selectListItems = GetAll();
            var searchSelectedValueFromDropdownList = selectListItems.Where(item => item.Value == dropdownChangedValue).First().Text;
            SelectedValue = searchSelectedValueFromDropdownList;
        }
    }
```

Razor cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.OnDropdownValueChangeModel
@{
}
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="MyMethod">
    <select class="form-control"
            asp-for="ProductTypeId"
            asp-items="Model.selectListItems"
            onchange="this.form.submit();">
    </select>
</form>

@if (@Model.SelectedValue != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
       <label>Your seleted value were:</label> @Model.SelectedValue
    </div>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you still need any further assistance you could [refer to this sample.](https://github.com/kironiitdu/Dotnet6App/blob/master/RazorPageDemoApp/Pages/OnDropdownValueChange.cshtml.cs)